# Отключить предупреждения сторонних библиотек

Tags: c++, cmake

Можно ли как-то отключить предупреждения, которые появляются при компиляции header-only сторонних библиотек, но при этом оставить предупреждения, касающиеся моего кода? Желательно, не изменяя сорсов, а с помощью конфига CMake.

Подключение какой-то бустовской header-only библиотеки к приложению:

```
add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE Boost::boost)
```

Если просто добавить `-Wall -Wno-format` к `app`, то отключатся и его предупреждения. А надо, чтобы только те, которые в сорсах буста возникают.

Comment: Вряд ли это возможно средствами cmake, так как эти предупреждения возникают из-за того, что препроцессор вставляет весь код из хэдэра в cpp, который и компилируется. Тобишь вряд ли возможно установить опцию для части файла.

Comment: CMake точно не поможет - это только если оборачивать каждый инклуд буста в коде: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html

Comment: модули, вероятно, вас спасут, но они пока еще на стадии эксперимента

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй это

```
add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_include_directories(app SYSTEM PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```